# ASP (classic) debugging?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, asp-classic

I'm trying to debug some ASP code I inherited without using IIS, just the remote website and the testing website. Is there a decent *freeware* debugger available without using Visual Studio?

I don't want to litter my code with <%='stuff'%> and I want to be able to trace the code through JavaScript…

Comment: What do you mean "without IIS"? So how the remote server hosts ASP files?

Comment: And how is Visual Studio Community Edition not freeware anyway? Use the tool that was designed for the task.

Comment: Given that JavaScript is client-side and ASP is server-side, I don't understand how you expect to be able to "trace the code through JavaScript".

Comment: Let me describe more precisely what I have in mind: I'm using Dreamweaver CS5. On the screen I have a number of items, one of which is a select/option box, the contents of which comes from an Access database sitting on the remote server. As the user scrolls through the database entries he will eventually select an item. The Onchange will eventually cause the value= to be ' returned' to a function up in the header. I wish for that function to open the database ' seek' that particular record in the database and using that returned Recordset to populate some of the fields up on the screen.

Comment: @greenber... so what you want is AJAX functionality. (Which has nothing to do with what particular techniques you use for debugging...) I would suggest writing a page that has the form with your dropdown, plus a submit button. When the form is submitted, return the fields you want and write them all out in a `<div>`. Once you have that working, write some JavaScript that does the actual form submission, and some more JavaScript to get the content of the `<div>` and put it where you want it.

Comment: Gosh, that sounds like a lot of work! I also don't like the idea of the user having to depress a submit button when they are making a selection: the idea is for the user to see partial records in the select/option box and then you see some additional fields filled in as they scroll through the select/option box and then when they see the record that they want they can then fill in additional fields finally hitting a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. From what i understand from your question, it seems you are avoiding Visual Studio because you are looking for a free alternative. Visual Studio Community, is  the free version and powerful enough for most users. 
 ̶A̶s̶ ̶l̶o̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶I̶I̶S̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶t̶a̶l̶l̶e̶d̶ ̶,̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶a̶u̶t̶o̶-̶s̶t̶a̶r̶t̶ ̶I̶I̶S̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶n̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶i̶t̶s̶ ̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶o̶f̶f̶.̶ Correction, you dont need IIS installed as it starts a builtin webserver.

For debugging in VS , right click on your code and select "View in Browser"

Comment: VS will use its own built in webserver (I think Microsoft call it Cassini) which does not support classic asp, unless IIS or IIS Express is specified as the dev server

Comment: (What happened to the rest of the partial answers in this thread?)